# Move window from display :0.0 to display :10.0?

Tags: ssh, lubuntu

I'm using Cygwin to login to my lubuntu box:

```
ssh -y *user*@192.168.12.37
```

I can easily use *byobu* to redeem my **cli** session. Is there a way to move a running window from display :0.0 to my remote session (:10.0)?

I ask because my lubuntu box is hooked to the HDTV in the living room, and I give my kids priority to do their educational stuff on the big screen. I then (try to) pick up where I left off on a netbook Cygwin session. Usually I have to quit everything and restart on the netbook.

Comment: Move? I'm not sure, but if you want to run a new application, run it like this: `DISPLAY=:10 foo`

Comment: Thanks, @lkjoel. I had been trusting applications to be GTK aware and ran them like this:
 `foo -display :10.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to attach a running application to another X display. The X protocol mandates that clients exit when they lose connection to the X server.

Comment: Thank you, @Dennis. I will remember this. Perhaps I will find a way to restart a client on a different X display.