# Show window from another display

Tags: xorg

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217246/move-window-from-display-0-0-to-display-10-0), I learned that I can't move windows between displays. But, can I show the contents of the window on another display somehow? Don't move it, but duplicate the output.

[On the Bumblebee website](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ) is stated that it launches a second X server and uses VirtualGL to show the output of this second server on the other. Couldn't this approach be applied to classic X windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [xpra](http://xpra.org), which could solve your problem. It starts your program in a virtual xserver (by default `xvfb`) and allows you to attach the display locally or remote. It describes itself as an `screen` for `X`.

So all you need to do is

```
xpra start :100 --start-child=myprogram
```

on the initial display and

```
xpra attach :100
```

on the other display.

Comment: Thanks, it works flawessly! Surprisingly, it's a relatively new piece of software, and it's evolving fast with new features. It seems we'll probably be missing X after all! :)